# Numpy slice and join

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy

I have an array that I would like to slice into multiple arrays in the form of:

```
M = [1,2,3          to [ [1],[2]....[9] ]  (List of arrays)
     4,5,6
     7,8,9]
```

And I would like to know how to join them back to get M again.
I can't find any other solution than to name each array and place it in its correct (row,column) position manually.

EDIT:

I found that my explanation was unclear. What I have is a big array that I would like to slice it into subarrays.

```
  M.shape = (5000,5000,3)    =====> L = [ subarray1, subarray2 ...]
  with subarray.shape = (500,500,3)
```

Second Step: Merging back

```
from L = [ subarray1, ...] to M
```

Thank for your help !

Comment: `[[i] for i in M]` ?

Comment: I'm sry i'm still not good in numpy...can you explain it for me ? the idea is that M can be an image

Comment: @hdatas elaborate more. give us some example of how would you slice it. Its not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way

```py
M = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
A = M.reshape(-1,1)
print(A)
#for getting back in the original form
a = len(A)
c = [A[i-3:i] for i in range(3,a+1,3)]
c_new = np.array([np.concatenate(i) for i in c]).reshape(3,3)
print(c_new)
```

A--

```py
[[1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [4]
 [5]
 [6]
 [7]
 [8]
 [9]]
```

c_new --

```py
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
```